Defining a covariant derivative from a connection using an explicit example
I was looking at the definition of an Ehresmann connection here. I thought it would be a good idea to try to explicitly define the connection for the case of a sphere $S^2$. So we have
$$
S^2 = \{(x,y,z) \mid x,y,z\in\mathbb{R}, x^2+y^2+z^2=1\}.
$$
We can then construct the tangent bundle $TS^2$ to be
$$
TS^2 = \{(x,y,z,u,v) \mid x,y,z,u,v\in\mathbb{R}, x^2+y^2+z^2=1\}
$$
where $x,y,z$ represent a point on the sphere and $u,v$ are components of a tangent vector at point $(x,y,z)$. I used the definition in the first section of the Wikipedia page on tangent bundle.
After that, we can define the projection map $\pi:TS^2\rightarrow S^2$ where
$$
\pi(x,y,z,u,v) = (x,y,z).
$$
In the article, we need the push forward $d\pi:TE\rightarrow TM$ where $E$ is the total space and $M$ is the base space. In our example, the total space is $TS^2$, and the base space is $S^2$. Therefore, we need to define $TTS^2$. I define it to be
$$
TTS^2 = \{(x,y,z,u,v,a,b,c,d) \mid x,y,z,u,v,a,b,c,d\in\mathbb{R}, x^2+y^2+z^2=1\}
$$
where $(x,y,z,u,v)$ represents a point on $TS^2$. Since $TS^2$ is a four-dimensional surface, the tangent vectors at a point need four components to describe them. The four components are represented by $a,b,c,d$.
We can then define the push forward to be
$$
d\pi(x,y,z,u,v,a,b,c,d)=(x,y,z,u,v);
$$
note that this is a projection from $TTS^2$ to $TS^2$.
Then, the vertical subbundle $V$ is
$$
V = \ker(d\pi)=\{(x,y,z,0,0,a,b,c,d)|x,y,z,a,b,c,d\in\mathbb{R}, x^2+y^2+z^2=1\}
$$
because $d\pi(x,y,z,0,0,a,b,c,d) = (x,y,z,0,0)$ which is the zero vector at point $(x,y,z)$.
The horizontal subbundle $H$ is
$$
H = \{(x,y,z,u,v,0,0,0,0) \mid x,y,z,u,v\in\mathbb{R}, x^2+y^2+z^2=1\}
$$
because it must satisfy $TTS^2=V\oplus H$. If we take $(x,y,z,u,v,0,0,0,0)\in H$ and $(x,y,z,0,0,a,b,c,d)\in V$ then the sum of these vectors is defined to be
$$
(x,y,z,u,v,0,0,0,0)+(x,y,z,0,0,a,b,c,d)=(x,y,z,u,v,a,b,c,d)
$$
so the first three components just keep track of what point of $S^2$ we are on.
The following figure shows curve $\gamma$ on the sphere with its tangent vector. The vector $X$ is also placed on one point.

My question is the following: given a vector $X= \left(\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}},0,\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}},0,1 \right)$ and curve gamma $\gamma(\phi)\in S^2$ where
$$
\gamma(\phi)=\left(\frac{\cos\phi}{\sqrt{2}},\frac{\sin\phi}{\sqrt{2}},\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\right)
$$
which is a curve that just goes around the sphere above the equator. This curve should have field
$$
\overline{\gamma}(\phi)=\left(\frac{\cos\phi}{\sqrt{2}},\frac{\sin\phi}{\sqrt{2}},\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}},1,0 \right)
$$
because the tangent vectors "point" in the same direction. See Figure 1.
Using the connection, we should be able to compute the following covariant derivative
$$
\nabla_X \overline{\gamma}
$$
at point $\left(\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}},0,\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\right)$.
In the Wikipedia article, they talk about horizontal lifts and their uniqueness. I can see this because the horizontal lift of $X$ is
$$
\tilde{X}= \left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}},0,\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}},0,1,0,0,0,0 \right) \in H
$$
and the horizontal lift of $\bar{\gamma}(\phi)$ is
$$
\tilde{\bar{\gamma}}(\phi) = \left(\frac{\cos\phi}{\sqrt{2}},\frac{\sin\phi}{\sqrt{2}},\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}},1,0,0,0,0,0 \right) \in H.
$$
These are unique in the horizontal subbundle. But after this, I have no clue how to use the connection to define a $\nabla$. Is it even possible?

Slow down. How is what you wrote $TS^2$?

My apologies, I added reasoning for why I defined $TS^2$ in that manner.

This is plain wrong. You need to learn from some serious textbooks, not from Wikipedia. You are ignoring the geometry of the submanifold … how does this reflect the tangent planes of the sphere as opposed to a plane?

I have not considered "how does this reflect the tangent planes of the sphere as opposed to a plane" I am not sure what that means.  I will then look around in some differential geometry texts book to understand how to construct the tangent space bundle of a manifold.

Start with Guillemin and Pollack’s Differential Topology.

I also think it’s important to understand the Levi-Civita connection of a surface in $\mathbb{R}^3$ and how to compute it for the sphere before you try to understand the Ehresmann connection. Is there some reason why you want to study it?

@TedShifrin Thank you for the suggestion. I will look into the book.

@Deane My goal was to start with a bare differentiable manifold like $S^2$. Then slowly add structure to it by defining a connection. Then try answering questions like how does the covariant derivative change depending on the choice of connections. These were just some thoughts I had.

But why an Ehresmann connection? It’s a pretty specialized concept.

@Deane The main reason is because I understand what are fiber bundles and  principal G-bundles. An Ehresmann connection can be defined on these objects without anymore structure so I thought it would be interesting to see what such a connection allows you to do. It seems my intuition of $TS^2$ is wrong once I get that sorted I will come back to this question again.

Let me suggest that although intuition can help a lot, you should understand better how to define and work with the tangent bundle of a surface and, specifically, a sphere, rigorously and not via intuition.
